# PayPal v1 API: 404 error on payment execute step

Tags: php, api, paypal, legacy

I have a project that uses PayPal. I get a 404 error on execution of some payments.

We use payment link and processing payments via callback on our server.
PayPal API v1 via official PayPal PHP SDK v2.0-beta.

Code for link:

```php
$request = new PaymentCreateRequest();
$request->body = $body;

$client = $this->getPayPalClient();//Preformed client
$result = $client->execute($request);

//And use $result->result->links[1]->href ...
```

Code for PayPal callback:

```php
if (empty($_GET['paymentId']) || empty($_GET['PayerID'])) {
//Some errors handling
}

$request = new PaymentGetRequest($_GET['paymentId']);

$client = $this->getPayPalClient();//Preformed client
$response = $client->execute($request);

$paymentId = $response->result->id;
$payerId = $response->result->payer->payer_info->payer_id;

$request = new PaymentExecuteRequest($paymentId);
$request->body = [
    "payer_id" => $payerId
];

try {
    $response = $client->execute($request);
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    if ($ex->statusCode == "400") {
        //Handle client errors
    }
    //Handle other errors; 404 error now
}

//Our system payment processing
```

For most payments I don't have any problems, but some payments I get errors on 'execute' step -

> 404 error (INVALID_RESOURCE_ID)

I see that payment was approved (on my PayPal dashboard) and by API.

I have two qestions:

1. Is `ExecutePayment` step necessary?
2. Why do I get the error for some payments?